# My timer is not working inside my loop

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockSummonElemental(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getFoodLevel() > 10){
        if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BLAZE_POWDER){
            List<Block> targets = player.getLineOfSight((Set)null, 100);
            final Creature blaze1 = (Creature) player.getWorld().spawnCreature(player.getLocation(), EntityType.BLAZE);
            final Creature blaze2 = (Creature) player.getWorld().spawnCreature(player.getLocation(), EntityType.BLAZE);
            for (Block target : targets){
                player.playEffect(target.getLocation(), Effect.SMOKE,5);
                List<Entity> victims = (List<Entity>) target.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(target.getLocation(), 2, 2, 2);
                for (Entity victim2 : victims){
                    final LivingEntity victim = (LivingEntity) victim2;
                    if (victim != blaze1){
                        if (victim != blaze2){
                            if (victim != player){
                                blaze1.setTarget(victim);
                                blaze2.setTarget(victim);
                                int count = 0;
                                while (count < 6) {
                                    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                                        public void run(){
                                            blaze1.setTarget(victim);
                                            blaze2.setTarget(victim);
                                            if (blaze1.getTarget() == player){
                                                blaze1.damage(20);
                                            }
                                            if (blaze2.getTarget() == player){
                                                blaze2.damage(20);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },50);
                                    count = count + 1;
                                }
                                blaze1.damage(20);
                                blaze2.damage(20);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        int manaused = player.getFoodLevel();
        manaused = manaused - 10;
        player.setFoodLevel(manaused);
        }
    }
```

I am using a timer to check whether the blazes attack the player who casts them, and resets the target. I don't know why, but nothing inside my loop happens. Sometimes, the blazes die instantly, sometimes, the blazes just spawn and that's it, sometimes it spawns blazes and throws an error, saying 'could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to Plugin v1.0'. I'm certain it's because of my use of runTaskLater; i have got it to work before, but in a loop it behaves differently. I don't know why this is happening, can anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Oh this seems to be a quite futuristic construct! Would recommend you to refactor it or at least hide the complexity by splitting it into different functions!

Comment: Not related to the problem you are solving, but you should try to reduce the amount of indentation in this block of code. You can negate some of your if statements and return early to avoid some of it. For example, `if (a > 10) { ... }` can becoming `if (a <= 10) { return; }`

Comment: does it work if you remove .getServer()

Comment: Damaging the blazes by 20 HP is effectively killing them, so your code will always immediately kill the blazes once a target is found. Your loop is also scheduling an identical task six times that executes ~2.5 seconds after scheduling. The if statements inside the run() method will never execute since you check that the victim is not the player or one of the two spawned blazes. What in detail is it that you are trying to do? Should the blazes cycle through all the entities in sight? Are you just trying to stop them from attacking the player? Right now this code is not making a lot of sense.

Comment: Let me just clarify what it's supposed to do. It summons two blazes, that fight a target for 10 seconds and die. It checks if the blazes are targetting the player (which i don't want) every 50 ticks, if they are, they are killed.

Answer (score 1):

The `BukkitRunnable` class is very useful in situations when you want to schedule a slightly more complex task (it's much easier for example to cancel the task after a certain action has been completed as the BukkitRunnable can cancel itself).

The `targetSelector` for blaze entities is set to target the nearest human entity, therefore spawning the blazes right next to the player is inevitably going to lead to them targeting the player pretty soon and getting killed (when using your code). Instead of killing the blazes when they target the player, it would probably be better to constantly re-set their target so that they attack only the specified entity.

A more elegant solution would be to create custom blazes that do not have the target selector or at least a modified version so that they don't constantly try to find the nearest player.

I have some code below with explanations that makes blazes attack the closest entity the player sees in his line of vision for 10 seconds. Note: Everything from finding the nearest entity in the player's view to implementing the target selection could be done in a multitude of different and probably better ways.

Here is the BlazeTask class with the run() method:

```
public class BlazeTask extends BukkitRunnable {

    int ticks = 0; //Tick counter to keep track of how long this task has been running

    private Blaze[] blazes; //The blazes
    private LivingEntity target; //The target

    public BlazeTask(Location location, LivingEntity target, int amount) { //The location where the blazes will be spawned, the target and the amount of blazes you want to spawn
        blazes = new Blaze[amount]; //Initialize the blaze array
        for (int i = 0; i < blazes.length; i++) { //Spawn as many blazes as we specified at the location
            //Also, shift the spawn location by up to a block (random) so that the blazes aren't clumped
            blazes[i] = (Blaze) location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location.clone().add(Math.random() - Math.random(), Math.random() - Math.random(), Math.random() - Math.random()), EntityType.BLAZE);
        }
        this.target = target; //Set the target variable
    }

    public void run() {
        if (++ticks > 20 * 10) { //If this task runs every tick, 200 ticks will equal approximately 10 seconds
            cancelTask(); //Cancel the task if this task has been running for 10 seconds or more
        }
        if (!isValid(target)) { //If the target has died or is null, the blazes have completed their goal
            cancelTask(); //Cancel the task (kill the blazes too)
        }

        int invalidAmount = 0; //Amount of blazes that are either null or dead
        for (Blaze blaze : blazes) {
            if (isValid(blaze)) { //If the blaze is still there
                Entity currentTarget = blaze.getTarget(); //Get the target
                if (currentTarget == null || !currentTarget.equals(target)) { //If the blaze doesn't have a target or the target is not the one we want
                    blaze.setTarget(target); //Re-set the target
                }
            } else { //If the blaze is dead or gone, increment the counter
                invalidAmount++;
            }
        }

        //If for some reason, all the blazes were killed within the 10 seconds, cancel this task
        if (invalidAmount == blazes.length) {
            this.cancel();
        }
    }

    //This method is used above
    private void cancelTask() { //Cancel the task by killing all blazes and also cancelling the task itself
        for (Blaze blaze : blazes) {
            if (isValid(blaze)) {
                blaze.damage(20);
            }
        }
        this.cancel();
    }

    //This method is also used in the above run() method
    private boolean isValid(Entity entity) { //Returns true if an entity is not dead and not null
        return entity != null && !entity.isDead();
    }

}
```

And here is how I use the BlazeTask class as well as find the nearest entity in the player's vision:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getFoodLevel() < 11) { //This is the reverse of player.getFoodLevel() > 10
        return; //If the food level is 10, 9, 8 etc., don't do anything
    }
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() != Material.BLAZE_POWDER) {
        return; //If the player is NOT holding blaze powder, don't do anything
    }

    List<Block> sight = player.getLineOfSight((Set) null, 100); //Get the blocks in sight

    //Get closest entity code
    for (Block block : sight) {
        player.playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.SMOKE, 1); //Play the smoke effect
        List<Entity> entities = (List<Entity>) block.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(block.getLocation(), 2, 2, 2); //Get entities near block
        if (entities.isEmpty()) { //If there are no nearby entities, continue to the next block in sight
            continue;
        }
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            if (!(entity instanceof LivingEntity)) { //If the nearby entity is not a LivingEntity, continue onto the next nearby entity
                continue;
            }
            LivingEntity victim = (LivingEntity) entity; //The closest living entity
            if (victim.equals(player)) { //If the entity is the player itself, continue onto the next nearby entity
                continue;
            }
            BlazeTask task = new BlazeTask(player.getLocation().clone().add(0, 4, 0), victim, 2); //Initialize the task, the 2 at the end is the number of blazes
            task.runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1); //Run the task with a 0 tick delay and a period of 1 tick (run every tick)
            player.setFoodLevel(player.getFoodLevel() - 10); //Lower food level
            return; //Return so that the loop is exited and we don't keep checking blocks/entities
        }
    }
}
```